# Wp addthis custom share url

Tags: wordpress, addthis

Need to share a custom url which includes the image #ID, so that the url looks the following in addthis:

http://www.mywebsite.com/mygallery/#image-1

Take a look at the following gallery and click on an image: 
http://www.starbasket.fr/photos-des-camps/camps-2011/la-baule-3/

Hoe do you include the #image-1 within the share link?
Which WP code echo's out the image ID?

I've tried the following code snippets, but it does not work:

```
<?php echo $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ); ?>
<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id() ?>
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $unfiltered ); ?>
```

Regards,
Charl

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit gallery's files.
Look in `/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/view/`
You'll find several files, the one you want to edit is "`gallery.php`".

Replace the title which usually diplays the alternate text (`$image->alttext`).
As the gallery take the "`title`" of each thumbnail to diplay it bigger, you can put your html code here (you also have to encode it) :

Try mine (the one you want) :

```
<?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>

<div id="ngg-image-<?php echo $image->pid ?>" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box" <?php echo $image->style ?> >
    <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >
    <?php $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."%23".$image->pid;
        $url2 = $image->imageURL;
        $url3 = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."#".$image->pid; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" id="<?php echo $image->pid ?>" title="<?php //echo $image->alttext ?><?php
        echo '&lt;div class=&quot;nggfb&quot; style=&quot;float:left;width:80px&quot; class=&quot;share-custom&quot; &gt;&lt;a class=&quot;share-custom sd-button&quot;  href=&quot;javascript:postToFeed(\''.$url3.'\',\''.$url2.'\');&quot; style=&quot;float:left&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;background-image:url(&amp;quot;http://www.starbasket.fr/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/sharedaddy/images/facebook.png&amp;quot;);&quot;&gt;Partager&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;tweets&quot; style=&quot;width:100px;float:left&quot;&gt;
    &lt;iframe allowtransparency=&quot;true&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; src=&quot;http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?url='.$url.'&amp;counturl='.$url.'&amp;hashtags=StarBasket&amp;related=campstarbasket&amp;via=campstarbasket&amp;text=Une photo ! '.$url2.'&quot; style=&quot;width:130px; height:20px;&quot;&gt;Tweet&lt;/iframe&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div style=&quot;float:left;width:80px;&quot;&gt;
    &lt;iframe src=&quot;/wp-content/googleplus.php?url='.$url.'&quot; marginheight=&quot;0&quot; marginwidth=&quot;0&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; style=&quot;border:0;width:100px;height:20px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
    &lt;meta itemprop=&quot;image&quot; content=&quot;'.$url2.'&quot;&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;a class=&quot;small-button smallblack &quot; style=&quot;height: 18px;padding-top: 0;&quot; onClick=&quot; return copy(\''.$url3.'\')&quot; href=&quot;'.$url3.'&quot;&gt;Copier&lt;/a&gt;' ?>" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
            <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
            <img title="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
            <?php } ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if ( $image->hidden ) continue; ?>
<?php if ( $gallery->columns > 0 && ++$i % $gallery->columns == 0 ) { ?>
    <br style="clear: both" />
<?php } ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I made different url because of facebook and the copie/paste function ("#" or is html code "%23") et I also get the file url in order to display on some twitter client without access the web page. And for Facebook, you can use the share function, because it takes the meta og:url of you whole page (without "#imageID"), so I choose the dialog function to do so.
Google+ takes the good one but not the thumbnail.